# Inserir mais itens em um ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

sou iniciante na programação Java/Android, e gostaria de uma ajuda, no que diz respeito à adicionar itens à um ListView.

O app recebe os 5 primeiros registros de um Json (Url), e adiciona na ListView, até aqui, tudo certo.

O app exibe então um botão, que ao clicar, consulta os próximos 5 registros.

**Aqui está minha dúvida**: o app substitui os 5 primeiros registros, pelos 5 próximos, e preciso que esta nova consulta de conteúdo seja adicionado ao final da ListView e não substituir o que já estava.

Segue abaixo, trechos do código

Activity Principal

```
// Populando Campeoes ListView
private void popularCampeoes() {
    ArrayList<Campeoes> newCampeoes = Campeoes.fromJson(JsonCampeoes);
    CampeoesAdapter adapterCampeoes = new CampeoesAdapter(this, newCampeoes);

    ListView listClubeCampeoes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listClubeCampeoes);
    listClubeCampeoes.setAdapter(adapterCampeoes);
}
```

Com o Json baixado, o app invoca o método popularCampeoes();

CampeoesAdapter

```
class CampeoesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Campeoes> {

    CampeoesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Campeoes> campeoes) {
        super(context, 0, campeoes);
    }

    private Context context;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        final Campeoes campeoes = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.campeoes_linha, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clubeCampTitulo);
        TextView tvConteudo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clubeCampConteudo);

        assert campeoes != null;

        tvTitulo.setText(campeoes.CampTitulo);
        tvConteudo.setText(campeoes.CampConteudo);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Já agradeço de imediato, qualquer ajuda que tiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De cada vez que receber novos registos deve adicioná-los ao ArrayList e não criar um novo. O mesmo se aplica ao Adapter.

Declare as varáveis `listCampeoes` e `adapterCampeoes` como atributos da Activity:

```
private ArrayList<Campeoes> listCampeoes;
private CampeoesAdapter adapterCampeoes;
```

No método `onCreate()` crie o *ArrayList* e o *Adaptar*:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    ...
    ArrayList<Campeoes> listCampeoes = new ArrayList<>();
    CampeoesAdapter adapterCampeoes = new CampeoesAdapter(this, listCampeoes);

    ListView listClubeCampeoes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listClubeCampeoes);
    listClubeCampeoes.setAdapter(adapterCampeoes);

    ...
}
```

No método `popularCampeoes()` adicione os novos registos ao *ArrayList* e notifique o *Adapter*:

```
// Populando Campeoes ListView
private void popularCampeoes() {
    ArrayList<Campeoes> newCampeoes = Campeoes.fromJson(JsonCampeoes);
    listCampeoes.addAll(newCampeoes);
    adapterCampeoes.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Perfeito ramaral, com a sua explicação simples e objetiva, consegui compreender a diferença entre a forma que estava escrito e a forma que voce deixou como exemplo. Muitíssimo obrigado !!!!